# JqueryUI slider handle stuck on the div border and handle donot reaches max value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hi guys I'm a Jquery noob ,I'm using jqueryUI slider but the slider handle always stucks on div border (left side) and after clicking on the slider bar it moves forward but doesn't reaches max limit and stucks in between.

Check the **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VaMJ2/1/)** the snapshot is from the browser (where you can see the slider handle) ,I have put all the code on fiddle ,but can't make jsFiddle work.

[image]

*Slider:*
 1. Slider handle sticks to the div border.
 2. Slider handle doesnt move towards the max value and stucks at some value in between.

Comment: Your demo doesn't work for me, looks like you haven't included the JavaScript for the slider plugin.

Comment: @cchana I have included jqueryUI method `.slider()` which converts element into slider check the image and fiddle.I'm little confuse on how to use the jsfiddle ,I have also posted the code in question.

Comment: Got the demo working: http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/QuFtg/ - was missing the jQuery UI CSS

Comment: @cchana Well thanks for that I have updated jsfiddle ,I have also fixed this a moment ago,but the real problem is defined in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that you have specified `ui.values[0]` instead of `ui.value`, to get the value. The  second problem is that `range: true` is not a valid option. I [updated the example with `range: 'min'`](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/QuFtg/2/) to show it working as expected.

Comment: Well If I comment the `range` it still works fine ,then for what purpose range is ?

Comment: I remembered I followed `range:true` from JqueryUI documentation ,it was used in `range slider`.

Comment: Thanks `Charanjit Chana` for the help :)

Comment: range is really there to allow you to select two values on the same slider, literally a range. The other use is to provide an anchor so that you can have a visual representation of the min->current value growing OR the current value->max shrinking, see http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemin

Comment: Ok thanks for it ,Well is there a resource on jquery internal workings ,I mean what objects it makes to perform all the magic not just how to use it blindly !